# I uninstalled Chromium. Why still extra ffmpeg codecs for the chromium browser in ubuntu update?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, ffmpeg

Chromium kept crashing on the gmail webpage (aw snap) and I have uninstalled it and installed goggle chrome.

In software updater, I see "extra ffmpeg codecs for the chromium browser" is this for google chrome?

Comment: It's probably in a different package. Try uninstalling it separately - I think it's chromium-codecs-ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

According to the output of `apt-cache depends google-chrome-stable`, nothing with `codecs` or `ffmpeg` is part of google-chrome-stable dependencies. If you want, you can safely remove "extra ffmpeg codecs for the chromium browser". To see this for yourself, open a terminal and run the code given above.

If you later change your mind and want to go back to Chromium, the system will re-install the necessary dependencies for you.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer was [here](http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/vivid/universe/c/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra/uninstall/index.html).
To uninstall just the codecs:

`sudo apt-get remove chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra`.

After running this command, close Ubuntu Software Center and try installing Chromium again, and it won't show the error.

In case there are still package issues, uninstall codecs and dependencies:

`sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra`.